# Disqus 2012 Appearance Tweaks

Tags: disqus

I am trying to change the appearance of the new Disqus (Disqus 2012).

Is there any way to modify the appearance of inputs and textareas in Disqus 2012 via CSS?

---

From what I can tell all appearance options have been removed and now Disqus smartly inherits your sites colours. The problem is that Disqus is not being smart. While it looks great on white backgrounds it is looking horrible on dark backgrounds.

I have a large client who wishes to upgrade to the new Disqus from the old but I see not way to change appearance.

My client has said that if I cannot upgrade her to the latest Disqus I need to remove Disqus completely. This will involve exporting nearly 500,000 comments..... this will not be fun!

The only information I have been able to find is here:

http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/545277-disqus-2012-appearance-tweaks

Answer (score 1):

Disqus detects and adapts to the template at hand by the main "font color"

If your theme is dark, like mine, you have to make sure that your body should look like this:

`body { font-size: 13px; color: white; background-color: #2c2c2c;}`

This is just an example, note that the variable that triggers DISQUS to use the dark theme is color:white,  also, put the `p {color:white}` just to be sure.

If you do this disqus 2012 will load a dark template from their servers into the iframe on your web and will look alot better.

Its not perfect, I am too pissed off about this but the iframe implementation is better than pure javascript and will easy things out for being SEO friendly.

Comment: The theme I am working with is quite complex. The main body is white so it has black text. However the comments sit outside the body on a black background. The layout is similar to the appstorm.com websites by envato http://android.appstorm.net/ there is no clean way to make Disqus 2012 work with a theme like this. It is pretty sad that they took this route. They could have implemented iframes but still allowed for css customization via the admin panel.

Comment: It's very difficult to fix disqus to understand your template. In that case you're out of luck, unless you change the color right on the comment section, but again, disqus 2012 does not understand anything about custom css, it just inherits your theme colors.

Comment: Which essentially means Disqus have broken their product for no reason at all. What a stupid move.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you have a body that's black, with white text, then a container div that's white with black text, and put the site inside that white div? That might work, I decided to leave the old disqus, I can't believe they did this. Can't even change the font or the input fields. Sucks!